# Get the parent object from child in entity framework without a foreign key

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, relationship

I am in charge of the View/View Model and not the Model of the project.  The Model is setup as such:

```
[Table("Activity")]
public class Activity
{
    [Key]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }

    public string OtherProperties { get; set; }
}

[Table("Class1")]
public class Class1
{
    [Key]
    public int Class1Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

[Table("Class2")]
public class Class2
{
    [Key]
    public int Class2Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

***I am trying to fill a DataGrid by doing a Call on the Activity class.  This Grid has a column for the "Name" property in the other class.***  How can I get a list of the "Name" column (or a list of the Class objects themselves) from the two Classes from the Activity class via the ViewModel?

**WPF**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
          Grid.Row="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Complete">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CompleteTaskCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:BasePage}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ActivityId}"
                            Content="{StaticResource FontAwesomeCheckIcon}"
                            Foreground="Green"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Style="{StaticResource FontAwesomeIconButton}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DueDate, StringFormat=MM/dd/yyyy, Converter={local:UtcToLocalDateTimeValueConverter}}" Header="Due Date"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsComplete, Converter={local:BooleanToStringParameterValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=CompletedOpen}" Header="Status"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Subject}" Header="Subject"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/> ??????????
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
Activities= DB.GetAll<Activity>().Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.AssignedTo == user);
```

**GetAll Method**

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : EcoDevBase, new()
{
    // if no items, returns an empty list
    IEnumerable<T> entityList = _Context.Set<T>().ToList();
    return entityList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what is your set up on the start, but there are ways to achieve your requirements, using LINQ. For example:

```
var desiredActivity = Activity;
var class1Names = DbContext.Class1.Where(e => e.Activities.Contains(desiredActivity).Select(e => e.Name)

var class2Names = DbContext.Class2.Where(e => e.Activities.Contains(desiredActivity).Select(e => e.Name)

var listOfNames = new List<string>;

listOfNames.AddRange(class1Names);
listOfNames.AddRange(class2Names);
```

It might not be the most optimal solution, but you didn't provided so much information about what you want to do with your business object.

Edit:

Referring, to your ViewModel, you have list of desired activities, now you want to know which Class object contains this activity, then you can do:

```
var listOfNames = new List<string>;
foreach (var activity in Activities)
{
 var class1Names = DbContext.Class1.Where(e => e.Activities.Contains(activity).Select(e => e.Name)

    var class2Names = DbContext.Class2.Where(e => e.Activities.Contains(activity).Select(e => e.Name)

    listOfNames.AddRange(class1Names);
    listOfNames.AddRange(class2Names);
}
```

Now, you can remove duplicates from listOfNames, by calling

```
var fixedListOfNames = new List<string>;
fixedListOfNames.AddRange(listOfNames.Distinct());
```

And if you want to get lists of your objects, you can do following:

```
 var listOfClasses1 = new List<Class1>;
var listOfClasses2 = new List<Class2>;
    foreach (var activity in Activities)
    {
     var class1Names = DbContext.Class1.Where(e => e.Activities.Contains(activity);

        var class2Names = DbContext.Class2.Where(e => e.Activities.Contains(activity);

        listOfClasses1.AddRange(class1Names);
        listOfClasses2.AddRange(class2Names);
    }
```

I'm unsure about your configuration, but you might also need to add

`using System.Data.Entity`

and/or `.Include(e => e.Activities)` to your queries.

Finally, If I were you, I'd create a business object class, containing properties, required by your DataGrid, to not work on db objects.

Comment: I am trying to fill a DataGrid by doing a Call on the Activity class.  This Grid has a column for the "Name" property in the other class.  That is what I am trying to get to.  I will also edit my question to provide this information.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't provide any code with logic, please provide some more, so I can edit my answer with more accurate code.

Comment: Edited, please check current solution.

Comment: Didn't even think of making a disposable object just for the data grid.  I might go that route.  I was looking for a more general way to get it because I have more than 2 classes that contain a list of activities, but this will work.  Thank you.